# How to thicken the waveform?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y  -i 'picture.png' -i 'audio.mp3' -filter_complex "[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono, showwaves=s=900x648:r=60:mode=p2p: colors=white[fg];  [0:v]scale=900:-1,crop=iw:648[bg]; [bg][fg]overlay=y=150[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -r 60 output.mp4
```

[It produces a waveform like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlGCb.png) I want to increase the thickness of this waveform line.

Comment: No such option in showwaves, but you can submit a [feature request](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: Using `mode=cline` might be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: You are right lol cline is in fact I used instead. Although a thick p2p would have been better. :(